# How import eclipse project to android studio 0.4.6 ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have project in eclipse and use android 2.3.3(API 10), but when I need import this project to android  studio 0.4.6 thin android show me massage to fixed my project after I click fixed show me error `"Execution failed for task ':preBuild'.> Build Tools Revision 19.0.0+ is required."
please how I can fixed this error.

That my gredle-wrapper .properties:

```
#Thu Apr 17 01:07:57 PDT 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

That my build.gradle:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 8
        buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['use','src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['use','src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['use','src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['use','src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        }
    }
```

Please till me, any version eclipse I can export project to import in android studio. 
All version eclipse is true to export.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Build Tools Revision to version 19.0.0 
open your sdk manager and update ( use the sdk directory associated with android studio not eclipse)

You might as well try to migrate your project from eclipse to make it easier when importing it in eclipse.

Let me know if this is not working